# Order List(Of DataRow) by Columntype String as Integer, VB

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a `list(of DataRow)` (each contained row is from the same table).

Each row contains the `.item("number")` as a `String`.
This item represents a `Number`.

What i need is a fast function, that `orders the rows` inside the List by the `.item("number")` `Ascending` (1->2->3->4->5)

**EDIT** The following is a response by me to a question asked about my question under this question! (Wow, thats a lot of questions..)

```
  grpname | grpID | LocationID | info1 | info 2 | Info 3
  yaya    | 2     | 4          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yaya    | 2     | 2          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yaya    | 2     | 3          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yaya    | 2     | 1          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yaya    | 2     | 5          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yo      | 6     | 4          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yo      | 6     | 1          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yo      | 6     | DBNULL     | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yo      | 6     | 2          | asd   | asd     | dasd
  yo      | 6     | 6          | asd   | asd     | dasd
```

Basicly thats what I have.
I get the information above by reading the Database of a 3rd party Application. My task is to put these into a nice looking word table in the order the user set in the mentioned 3rd Party tool. 
`LocationID` belongs to the `grpID`, so there is a specific order of the Rows inside the group while staying in the same `Datatable`. 
I was able to order the `DataRows` in the correct groups. To solve the Problem of putting the rows into the correct position in the groups i programmatically put all the rows of a group into a `list(of Datarow)` which is put into a `List(of List(of DataRow))`As soon as I have all the Rows ordered correctly inside the `Lists` i will reorder them inside the `DataTable`

**EDIT**
I finally found a solution myself using an additional Column with the following Content (describing as Text)

```
 Try to put CInt(LocationID) -> if Catch happens (DBNULL): Put 999
 After thats done: Use DataView to Order DataTable by grpID, newColumn
```

Primary it trys to order by grp, and when there are more than one rows of the same group it orders by newColumn.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why they are in a `List(Of T)` when you could manipulate them as easily in a `DataTable`.  Given a list named `rowList`:

```
rowList = rowList.OrderBy(Function(q) q.Item("number")).ToList
```

Comment: I tried to explain why I am not using a DataTable. The explanation is on the bottom of the Question. I hope i was able to explain it in an understandable way. I'll give that function a try. 

Could you explain me what exactly the following part does? `(Function(q) q.Item("number"))`.

Comment: Seems like this is ordering the column as String. I need it to be ordered as Integer. Also there is another problem i haven't mentioned yet; DBNull has to be handled some way

Comment: In my opinion you need to use a datatable. The datatable columns can be cast in the types required i.e integer were required. You would then be able to do whatever you need order, filter etc. Using a datatable you will be able to specify OrderBy grpID, LocationID so that the data is sorted by grpID and if you have many these are sorted by LocationID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you can see in the Question it is already solved.